# Eloquent whereHasNot is missing

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to access eloquent's `whereHasNot` method (added here:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/8f0cb08d8ebd157cbfe9fdebb54d2b71b0afaabd)

I have laravel/framework (v5.1.20) installed via composer.  However, the method does not exist in my `/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php` file.

Here is what I have in composer.json

```
"laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
```

Am I missing somewhere here?

If I'm not able to add this via composer, how can I extend Eloquent within my app to add this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It was renamed to [`whereDoesntHave`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/3615fa377dfab765b17e200566869a95502b2697) on Dec 17, 2014.

```
/**
 * Add a relationship count condition to the query with where clauses.
 *
 * @param  string  $relation
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public function whereDoesntHave($relation, Closure $callback = null)
{
    return $this->doesntHave($relation, 'and', $callback);
}
```